# OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError CSRF detected on going back from browser after successful login. Doorkeeper, devise, omniauth-oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, omniauth, doorkeeper

I've build an OAuth2 provider using the `doorkeeper` engine with `devise`. On my client app I'm using a custom `omniauth-oauth2 -v 1.3.1` strategy. Everything works well, but after I sign in if I hit the back button on the browser I get [image]

I dug into the omniauth-oath2 code and it appears that there are two methods that I think are closely related to this problem, one that creates the `session["omniauth.state"]` from the url params:

```
def authorize_params
        options.authorize_params[:state] = SecureRandom.hex(24)
        params = options.authorize_params.merge(options_for("authorize"))
        if OmniAuth.config.test_mode
          @env ||= {}
          @env["rack.session"] ||= {}
        end
        session["omniauth.state"] = params[:state]
        params
end
```

and one that checks this and deletes this from the session on the callback process:

```
def callback_phase # rubocop:disable AbcSize, CyclomaticComplexity, MethodLength, PerceivedComplexity
        error = request.params["error_reason"] || request.params["error"]
        if error
          fail!(error, CallbackError.new(request.params["error"], request.params["error_description"] || request.params["error_reason"], request.params["error_uri"]))
        elsif !options.provider_ignores_state && (request.params["state"].to_s.empty? || request.params["state"] != session.delete("omniauth.state"))
          fail!(:csrf_detected, CallbackError.new(:csrf_detected, "CSRF detected"))
        else
          self.access_token = build_access_token
          self.access_token = access_token.refresh! if access_token.expired?
          super
        end
      rescue ::OAuth2::Error, CallbackError => e
        fail!(:invalid_credentials, e)
      rescue ::Timeout::Error, ::Errno::ETIMEDOUT => e
        fail!(:timeout, e)
      rescue ::SocketError => e
        fail!(:failed_to_connect, e)
  end
```

It appears that somehow the first method is not called on going back from the browser. Does someone had the same problem and is there a solution to this problem without setting the `:provider_ignores_state` to `true`. Do I need to set something on the provider, I really don't get it, plus I can't seem to find this problem anywhere on the web and I highly doubt it I'm the first one that recognizes it, but I may be the first one that can't find a reasonable solution without affecting security.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: @JaimeRodas to be honest I didn't, the client wanted a simple JWT authorization to implement his SSO, and not Oauth2 provider. Either way it appears that the `callback_phase` method was called twice, which obviously will go to the failure application, because the second time there is no `session["omniauth.state"]` because it gets deleted. Now I don't know much of security but if you change this line to not get deleted I think it will pass. That is what I recall. There is where I stopped working because I needed something else, but thanks for reminding me I will take a look at this again.